# Vue template not binding properly in tests

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vue-component

I have a simple button component which I would like to test with `vue-test-utils`, `mocha-webpack`  and `jsdom`.

```
const Button = {
  props: {
    text: {default: 'Save draft'}
  },

  data: function () {
    return {
      disabled: false
    }
  },

  template: `
    <input
      v-bind:value='text'
      v-bind:disabled='disabled'
      type='submit' name='save' class='highlight'
    >
  ` 
}

export default Button
```

Everything works fine in the browser, but none of my `v-bind` attributes are rendering in my tests:

```
describe('Button', () => {

  it('has the right text', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(SaveDraftButton, {})
    wrapper.update()
    console.log(wrapper.html())

    expect(wrapper.hasAttribute('value', 'Save draft')).to.be.true
  })
})
```

The `console.log` output is `<input type="submit" name="save" class="highlight">`.

Non-attribute bindings (e.g. `<p>{{ text }}</p>`) work fine.

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong here? This seems like the simplest thing and I'm banging my head against it.

Comment: [Looks like this is a bug](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/v-bind-not-working-with-attributes-in-test/19894/4) in `jsdom` or `vue-test-utils`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a [feature and not a bug](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/v-bind-not-working-with-attributes-in-test/19894/6?u=velvetkevorkian) of `jsdom`.

Workaround:
`expect(wrapper.element.value).to.equal('Save draft')`